# Where to set transaction isolation level from java code?

Tags: java, mysql

I have to create a booking system in which I would like to set the isolation levels for transactions regarding the `createBooking()` methods.
I would like transactions to be serializable when I create a new booking and persist it to the database. Where do I do this in my java classes?
I have a Connection class, a `BookingDatabase` data access object class, and a BookingController which creates the booking from the GUI class.

EDIT: Included my BookingDatabase DAO class to show where i would like to have the isolation level

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import Database.*;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Model.Booking;
import Model.Room;
import Model.TimeInterval;
import Model.User;

public class BookingDatabase implements BookingDatabaseInterface {
    private static final String INSERT = "insert into Booking (roomName, title, bookingDescription, timeinterval, bookingDate, username) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    private PreparedStatement insertPS;
    private static final String DELETE = "delete from Booking where bookingId = ?";
    private PreparedStatement deletePS;
    private static final String FIND_BOOKINGS = "select r.roomName, r.roomNumber, r.location, r.roomDescription, "
            + "                                             u.username, u.password, u.emailAddress, u.phoneNo, employeeId, u.adminId, "
            + "                                              b.roomName, b.title, b.bookingDescription, b.timeinterval, b.bookingdate, b.username "
            + "                                              from Room as r, Users as u, Booking as b where b.roomName = r.roomName and b.username = u.username ORDER BY r.roomName";
    private PreparedStatement findBookingsPS;
    private static final String GET_BOOKING_Q = "select r.roomName, r.roomNumber, r.location, r.roomDescription, "
                                                + "u.username, u.password, u.emailAddress, u.phoneNo, employeeId, u.adminId, "
                                                + " b.roomName, b.title, b.bookingDescription, b.timeinterval, b.bookingdate, b.username "
                                                + " from Room as r, Users as u, Booking as b where b.roomName = r.roomName and b.username = u.username and bookingId = ?";
    private PreparedStatement getBookingPS;

private RoomDatabase roomDatabase;
    private UserDatabase userDatabase;

    private Connection connection = DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
    
    // Initialize class, get connection and initialize prepared statements
    public BookingDatabase(RoomDatabase roomDatabase, UserDatabase userDatabase) throws SQLException{
        init();
        this.roomDatabase = roomDatabase;
        this.userDatabase = userDatabase;
    }
    
    private void init() throws SQLException{
        Connection con = DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
        insertPS = con.prepareStatement(INSERT, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        deletePS = con.prepareStatement(DELETE, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        findBookingsPS = con.prepareStatement(FIND_BOOKINGS);
        getBookingPS = con.prepareStatement(GET_BOOKING_Q);
        connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
    }

@Override
    public int insert(Booking booking) {
        
        try {
        DBConnection.getInstance().startTransaction();
        connection.createStatement().execute("LOCK TABLES `Booking` WRITE");
        
        // Get the variables fromTime and ToTime to set into TimeInterval in database
        String fromTime = booking.getTimeInterval().getFromTime();
        String toTime = booking.getTimeInterval().getToTime();
            
        // Combine the two strings into a single string
        String timeInterval = fromTime + "," + toTime;
    
        // Insert attributes into booking
        insertPS.setString(1, booking.getRoom().getRoomName());
        insertPS.setString(2, booking.getTitle());
        insertPS.setString(3, booking.getBookingDescription());
        insertPS.setString(4, timeInterval);
        insertPS.setString(5, booking.getDate());
        insertPS.setString(6, booking.getUser().getUserName());
        
        
        // Run query
        insertPS.executeUpdate();
        
        
        // find and return a bookingId
        ResultSet resultSet = insertPS.getGeneratedKeys();
        resultSet.next();
        connection.commit();
        connection.createStatement().execute("UNLOCK TABLES");
        DBConnection.getInstance().commitTransaction();
        
        return resultSet.getInt(1);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        
        try {
            DBConnection.getInstance().rollbackTransaction();
            throw new RuntimeException("Transaction rollback");
        } catch (SQLException e1){
            throw new RuntimeException(e1);
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Connection` class has a [`setTransactionIsolation`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#setTransactionIsolation(int)) method. In you case:

```java
Connection con = // create the connection...
con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
```

Comment: The connection class I'm talking about is one i created myself in which i have the startTransaction() commit() etc. So it doesn't have setTransactionIsolation. Do you think i should set it to serializable in the myConnection class? 
I don't know if i want all transactions ever to be serializable, only the ones regarding createBooking()

Comment: @Torben presumably you have a `java.sql.Connection` object somewhere under the hood there. When you start the relevant transaction for `createBooking`, you need to call this option. If you want some advice on where this can fit in with your code, you'll need to share that code :-)

Comment: i have edited my post now, so you should be able to see the code. For now i called the setTransactionIsolation() in the init() method because i dont know where to put it :)